# Unity NavMesh ignoring additional colliders

Tags: unity-game-engine, navmesh

I am basically making a clone of the game "Clustertruck". To simplify the idea of the game: There are a bunch of trucks driving on a road and the player is on top of the trucks and needs to reach the finish line as fast as possible.

To navigate the trucks, I am using Unitys NavMeshSystem. Each truck has an Agent that drives along a route until the end is reached. Because of the cylinder shape of the NavMeshAgent, I added another collider that fills the rest of the truck:[image]

Now, when two trucks collide with each other there is a problem with the colliders. They clip in each other and it looks like the colliders are handled like a trigger:
[image]

The components of the truck are the following: [image]

Is there any way of preventing the clipping? The best way would probably be to make the NavMeshAgent aware of the other collider, but how do I do that?

Comment: You could try putting [Nav Mesh Obstacles](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-NavMeshObstacle.html) on the trucks, tho that will probably result in the agent seizing completely.  I don't remember Clustertruck too well, but weren't the trucks as dumb as rocks only capable of driving forward?

Comment: I will try if that works, thank you. The trucks do take curves as you can see [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mWFIKglQJ8c&t=134s)

Comment: I must have a bad memory then. In any case you can still program some very rudimentary obstacle avoidance with a couple of raycasts and just move them as rigidbodies.